# Openshift Spring App - How to make it run on ROOT?

Tags: spring, jboss, openshift

I currently have a spring application in openshift. 
The name of the app is "apps" and it runs on

```
http://apps-fxperiments.rhcloud.com/apps
```

but I want to make it run on the root

```
http://apps-fxperiments.rhcloud.com
```

Anyone who's got an experience on this?

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml, look for `webAppRootKey` and set it to /:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
  <param-value>/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: tried to look for webAppRootKey but found none, I'll try to add it then!

Comment: Here's what worked for me,
<context-root>/</context-root> in the jboss-web.xml

Comment: Ah, I didn't see you we're using JBoss. My bad

Comment: @FrancisFredrickValero Maybe you should add your solution as an answer and set it as the correct one for people who have the same problem